# Оформление checkout в woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Добрый день, помогите убрать на странице оформление заказа обертку `<p></p>` к `input`. Скрин примера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убирать его не надо совершенно. Вас беспокоит не `<p>`, а его padding и margin. Ну и уберите их в css:

```
p.form-row {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Примерно так. Настройте padding и margin по вкусу.

Comment: А убрать его нельзя ни как? Я то переписал стили но все же интересно.

Comment: Можно, надо лезть в код woocommerce. Причем с большой вероятностью, не удастся вынести этот код в свою тему. Т.е. слетит при первом обновлении wc. В общем, трудозатраты примерно на 10 умножьте.

Comment: Да, легче переписать просто стили, спасибо!)